# Host has offered me an off site deal for Airbnb

Tags: scams, airbnb

I made a reservation, but today the host called me and is claiming that my reservation is preventing other guests from booking those dates. The host wants me to accept an alteration request that reduces my reservation to 1 day (at a higher price), but has assured me that I will still get my full reservation so long as I pay the rest off-site using e-transfer or cash (and will lower the price for me). During the phone call I said I was okay with it, because I was caught off guard. After the call I brushed up on Airbnb policies, and it clearly states I risk my account (and their account) being closed if I proceed. I could also be getting scammed. I messaged (through Airbnb app) the seller to inform them I couldn't accept the change for these reasons, and then I declined the alteration request on Airbnb. Now I am worried I will show up, and not have a place to stay, or worse have a host that is mad at me for costing them money (since they can't book other guests). I don't know much about Airbnb. This is my first time using it! The host hasn't messaged me back since I declined the alternation. What am I supposed to do to? I cannot cancel my reservation, because I won't be refunded for any of my stay. What is the proper way to proceed in this scenario? Do I continue as planned, and hope the host holds up my original reservation? I was really hoping to have a stress-free trip :(

Comment: I'm confused. Why is it unexpected for the host that someone booking their property makes it unavailable for other people to book it on the same day? Isn't he basically saying he wants to double-book the property, which will ultimately screw over at least one of those parties? I don't understand how getting multiple people to book the property on the same day (which is his stated goal) could have any semblance of legitimacy.

Comment: Sounds like your host is doing something dodgy. Contact Airbnb, tell them what's going on, and ask them how to proceed. Hopefully you have enough time left to resolve the problem.

Comment: The host has multiple rooms.

Comment: Still dodgy. Each room should have a different Airbnb listing, and should be able to be booked through Airbnb for your entire stay.

Comment: 100% dodgy. Contact AirBnB immediately. Don't expect to actually stay at this place.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Host has since messaged me back, and says it's okay to continue with the original reservation through Airbnb. I checked their profile, and they've been hosting for less than 6 months. They only have a handful of reviews, but nearly all are positive. The only negative review is about cleanliness.

Comment: There are some similarities in this story to the scam described here: https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/43k7z3/nationwide-fake-host-scam-on-airbnb

Comment: The fact that they've already tried to pull this nonsense on you raises the likelihood that they'll have further nonsense in store later. Why hope that someone demonstrably dodgy will live up to their end of the bargain when there are so many other places to stay? I'd try to see if you can get Airbnb to cancel without charge.

Comment: @ZachLipton AirBNB, exercise goodwill, ever? LOL, case closed. Besides, you pay at the time of booking, so OP needs a refund, not a mere cancellation free of charge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Scam

The person wants you to pay through some sort of "e-transfer of cash".  Presumably, in advance.   This is the red hot glowing flag of scammery.

If the person had said "let me send you a PayPal invoice", okay maybe - since PayPal has Buyer Protection.  But this person wants you to pay using *their preferred method* which of course will be irreversible. This is outrageous! No legit hoster would have a problem with a scheme with buyer recourse e.g. Visa-Mastercard.

Stacked on top of this is the absurd claim that AirBnB (literally, Air *Bed & Breakfast*) would only support one room per account/venue. Real Bed & Breakfasts have between 3 and 20 rooms typically, so that would mean AirBnB couldn't handle its namesake!

The desire to go off-airBnB for most of the stay is, in itself, not that alarming. Regular hosts want to do this too.  But combined with these other things, it becomes another red flag.

There's a possibility that this is a hacked account.  Perhaps the account had gone inactive (an active host would immediately notice hacking) and the true account has only one unit to rent. That would explain why the scammer claimed that; to open up the other dates to create more slots to scam people. *Business must be good.*

If you wanted to toy with the person, you would say "be happy to pay you actual cash in-person at the venue".  That will get you a clever excuse!  Then you could offer to take a PayPal invoice.  It's unlikely the scammers would agree, but if they did, thet'd flag it as a "gift" (no recourse) rather than a "purchase of goods and services" (recourse) and hope you did not notice.

Comment: +1 just for the phrase _'red hot glowing flag of scammery'_!